# How to save the contents of dynamic tabs in a GUI with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tabs, save

I'm having trouble saving the contents of dynamic tabs in a GUI environment made with tkinter in Python. When I enter the contents and click the save button, the text file created only shows the contents of the last tab in the GUI. Here is the script I'm working with.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

variables = dict()

def add_vehicle_tab():
    v_info = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(v_info, text='Tab {}'.format(tab_control.index(tk.END)))
    #add content here

    variables['VEH_MAKE'] = tk.StringVar(value=' ')
    ttk.Label(v_info, text= 'VEH_MAKE').grid(row=2, column=0)
    ttk.Entry(v_info, textvariable=variables['VEH_MAKE']).grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))
    
    variables['COLOR'] = tk.StringVar(value=' ')
    ttk.Label(v_info, text= 'COLOR').grid(row=4, column=0)
    ttk.Entry(v_info, textvariable=variables['COLOR']).grid(row=5, column=0,sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))    

    variables['YEAR'] = tk.IntVar(value=' ')
    ttk.Label(v_info, text= 'YEAR').grid(row=6, column=0)
    ttk.Entry(v_info, textvariable=variables['YEAR']).grid(row=7, column=0,sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))

    tab_content['Tab {}'] = variables

def save_tabs():
    global records_saved
    make = variables['VEH_MAKE'].get()
    color = variables['COLOR'].get()
    year = variables['YEAR'].get()
    with open("C:/tabs_data.txt", "w") as file:
        for index, content in tab_content.items():
            file.write(f'VEH_MAKE = {make}'), file.write('\n')
            file.write(f'COLOR = {color}'), file.write('\n')
            file.write(f'YEAR = {year}'), file.write('\n')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Vehicle tabs')
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
tab_content = {}
add_tab_button = tk.Button(root, text='Add vehicle tab', command=add_vehicle_tab)
add_tab_button.pack()

save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Save Tabs", command=save_tabs)
save_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In the save_tabs() function, the script saves each item and then writes them to a new file. However, the script only saves the last tab. What do I need to do to this script to make it save all tabs?

Comment: Yeah, there were a few typos. Sorry for the confusion. I edited the post and made corrections.

Comment: When you assign `tab_content[tab_control.index(v_info)] = "Content for Tab{}".format(tab_control.index(tk.END))`, you're overwriting whatever `tab_control.index(v_info)` might happen to be with `"Content for Tab1"`. Also, `file_path: "C:/" + "/tabs_data.txt"` does nothing, and `folder_path` isn't being used in the file I/O block anywhere.

Comment: *"I'm not sure why the contents of the tabs (VEH_MAKE, COLOR, YEAR) are not being saved."* - it is because you have never done anything to save the content of those tkinter variables stored in `variables`.

Comment: I modified the script. I got rid of a few unnecessary lines, and I called each item in the save_tabs() function to be saved and written to a file. The script now saves the tab contents, but only the last tab. What do I need to write into the script to make it save all tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the content of `variables` are overwritten to store the last set of tkinter variables whenever `add_vehicle_tab()` is executed.  Also same *key* `"tab {}"` is used for `tab_content`, so `tab_content` has always one item.

To fix the issue:

- change `variables` to local variable instead
- use current tab name as the key of `tab_content`

Below is the updated code required:

```py
...
#variables = dict()  # don't use global variable

def add_vehicle_tab():
    v_info = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

    name = 'Tab {}'.format(tab_control.index(tk.END))
    tab_control.add(v_info, text=name)

    variables = {}  # use local variable

    variables['VEH_MAKE'] = tk.StringVar()
    ttk.Label(v_info, text= 'VEH_MAKE').grid(row=2, column=0)
    ttk.Entry(v_info, textvariable=variables['VEH_MAKE']).grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))

    variables['COLOR'] = tk.StringVar()
    ttk.Label(v_info, text= 'COLOR').grid(row=4, column=0)
    ttk.Entry(v_info, textvariable=variables['COLOR']).grid(row=5, column=0,sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))

    variables['YEAR'] = tk.IntVar()
    ttk.Label(v_info, text= 'YEAR').grid(row=6, column=0)
    ttk.Entry(v_info, textvariable=variables['YEAR']).grid(row=7, column=0,sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))

    # use tab name as the key
    tab_content[name] = variables

def save_tabs():
    with open("C:/tabs_data.txt", "w") as file:
        for name, variables in tab_content.items():
            make = variables['VEH_MAKE'].get()
            color = variables['COLOR'].get()
            year = variables['YEAR'].get()
            file.write(f'{name}:\n')
            file.write(f'VEH_MAKE = {make}\n')
            file.write(f'COLOR = {color}\n')
            file.write(f'YEAR = {year}\n')
...
```

---

I would suggest to save the content in JSON format:

```py
import json
...

def save_tabs():
    data = {name: {key:var.get() for key, var in variables.items()}
            for name, variables in tab_content.items()}
    with open("C:/tabs_data.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the solution I needed. The JSON format isn't particularly useful given how I want to use the created text file, but the solution of making the variables local and using the tab name as key did the trick. You are awesome, thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to dump some python data you might consider the ```pickle``` module.